# Base types or Complex types?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between Bool and Boolean types in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134746/what-is-the-difference-between-bool-and-boolean-types-in-c-sharp)

I'm doing a lot of C# programming for a web application these days. My team haven't made a decision on whether we should use base types or complex types.

What is the advantages of the different types?

Feks:

```
Object vs object
Boolean vs bool
```

and so on...

Thanks!

Comment: StyleCop says `Use the built-in type alias`. See no reason to have an exception

Comment: As others have said, they're just aliases: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7 etc.

Comment: 'int', 'float' and 'bool' are training wheels for people who still think like 'C' programmers.  You can think of them as __Big Boy Pants__ for engineers who aren't potty trained yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference - `bool` is an alias for `Boolean`, `object` is an alias for `Object`. However, idiomatic C# would have you use `object`, `bool`, `int`, etc.

Note that, by default, StyleCop will enforce this practice. The relevant rule is [SA1121](http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1121.html).

There are, of course, different opinions about whether the rule is valid. I would suggest reading this SO question: [C# - StyleCop - SA1121: UseBuiltInTypeAlias - Readability Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000517/c-sharp-stylecop-sa1121-usebuiltintypealias-readability-rules).

Answer (score 2):

[c#: difference between "System.Object" and "object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017282/c-difference-between-system-object-and-object)

Jon Skeet:

> string is an alias for global::System.String. It's simply syntactic
>   sugar. The two are exactly interchangable, and there'll be no
>   difference in the compiled code.
>
> Personally I use the aliases for variable names etc, but I use the CLR
>   type names for names in APIs, for example:
>
> ```
> public int ReadInt32() // Good, language-neutral
>
> public int ReadInt() // Bad, assumes C# meaning of "int"
> ```
>
> (Note that the return type isn't really a name - it's encoded as a
>   type in the metadata, so there's no confusion there.)

Comment: You misspelled Jon Skeet's name. May Jon have mercy on your soul.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt good spot lol

Comment: I only hope I caught it in time. He's [all-powerful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts), you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
object === System.Object
string === System.String
bool === System.Boolean
byte === System.Byte
sbyte === System.SByte
short === System.Int16
ushort === System.UInt16
int === System.Int32
uint === System.UInt32
long === System.Int64
ulong === System.UInt64
float === System.Single
double === System.Double
decimal === System.Decimal
char === System.Char
```