# Roslyn Code Fixes with type alias "string" - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: types, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, c#-6.0

I have Visual Studio 2015 with the latest version of Reshaper (9.1.2).

I tend to use a style of referring to Types and type aliases much the way [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7077/2283050) describes. I like the general look of making variable declarations with the type alias and using the System type for expressing static functions that exist for the type.

As an example:

```
string greet = String.Format("Hello {0}!", place);
```

With that said, I'm seeing a Roslyn Code Fix in my IDE to replace String for string.
[image: Before Roslyn improvement]

It asks to simplify...

[image: Roslyn Simplify name 'String']

And it comes out changing only the String to string:[image: 'String' changed to 'string']

**I want to what this change affects, and why.**

- Is it a performance improvement in compilation only?
- Does it add some minor speed benefits at runtime?
- Is there any other reason why I should care about this code improvement?

Comment: There's no performance improvement. `string` is an alias for `String`.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6000517/1698557

Comment: Is it just a suggestion in the sense that it is the official style, then?

Comment: Actually, it's an option in Code Style in Options.

Comment: @SLaks I'm not seeing it. http://i.imgur.com/k3A4DHm.png If you are refering to the built-in type naming, it's turned off.

Comment: @ZacharyDow: This is a Roslyn feature, not a Resharper feature.  Look in the VS native Options.

Comment: @SLaks Thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed to know after the fact that it doesn't do anything special :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, even now in the latest version of Visual Studio (2015) and the .NET (4.6) framework, string is still just an alias for String. It's simply a style suggestion from Visual Studio.

For anyone else who may want to remove this code style...

This setting can be turned off under: Tools => Options... => Text Editor => C# => Code Style => Prefer intrinsic predefined type keyword in member access expresssions.

[image: Setting visual]